# How to insert several images into HTML/CSS quickly?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to upload several images in an html file in a few lines? I have a folder of over a 100 images, and I want to put them into a gallery, based in HTML/CSS. However, I don't want to write:

```
<img src = "blah blah.jpg"> 
<img src = "blah blah2.jpg"> . . . 
<img src = "blah blah100.jpg">
```

I feel as though there must be a faster way to insert several images, like being able to direct the HTML file to the entire folder.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it without using a server side framework such as PHP/Rails etc.

To help you start, you'll need a server side language to pass your static information onto the client side and then a template language to loop through all the images.

Comment: Except you don't need a framework to do this.

Answer (score 0):

it is Compulsery to use The `src`attribute specifies the URL. you have to use `<img src="blah blag.jpg"` . but if you want to do like that then on server side you can do that .